# javascript regex url (url substring)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hey guys i have written a simple function which reads the current url and sets some kind of highlight.

If I open up the url everything works fine but if I do more advanced request it's not working.

example: If i request "/customers" it works but if I request "/customers/10" it's not working anymore.
Can someone provide me with some regex action ?

Thanks in advance

```
function setGUI() {
var url = window.location.pathname;
switch(url) {
    case "/orders":
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".nav li:nth-child(2)").addClass("active");
        });
        break;

    case "/customers": // match "customers/any_id"
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".nav li:nth-child(3)").addClass("active");
        });
        break;

    case "/partners": match "partners/anyid"
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".nav li:nth-child(4)").addClass("active");
        });
        break;

    case "/help":
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".nav li:nth-child(5)").addClass("active");
        });
        break;

    case "/users/": // match "/users/any_id/"
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".nav li:nth-child(6)").addClass("active");
        });
        break;

    default:
        alert("debug");
    }
}

setGUI();
```

Comment: switch cannot handle it.... you need to use `if elseif` construct

Comment: @ArunPJohny - There are (at least) two ways a switch can handle this requirement: (a) keep the existing switch but delete the end of the url before comparing, or (b) "cheat" with a `switch(true)` and put the conditions in each `case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your function doesn't need to use whatever information might be after the second slash, so I'd suggest simply deleting everything from the second slash onwards:

```
var url = window.location.pathname.replace(/^(\/[^/]+)\/.*/, "$1");
```

...and then leave your switch and case conditions as they are.

Comment: thanks this works for me... only "/users/id/edit" is not working. any ideas?

Comment: Your users case item is `case "/users/"` - try changing it to `case "/users"` (remove the trailing `/` so that it matches the format of the other urls).

Comment: I did still the same result

Comment: `"/users/id/edit".replace(/^(\/[^/]+)\/.*/, "$1");` returns `"/users"` (I just tested it to be sure), so it should work with `case "/users"`.

Answer (score 0):

Switch will evaluate base on equality. One solution is to use `if-else` instead.
I'd recommend using `indexOf`:

```
..
if(url.indexOf("/orders") > -1){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".nav li:nth-child(2)").addClass("active");
        });
}else if(url.indexOf("/customers") > -1){
..
```

Comment: _"You have to..."_ - Well no, you don't _have_ to, there are at least two ways that you can use a switch to achieve this. (Arguably an if/else if structure is better, but it's not the only way.)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll reword that sentence.